# Should I use Servlet for Database access and Display results in JSP using JSTL?

Tags: database, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, design-patterns

I've been learning Java for more than 6 months. I'm developing a web app and learning through building it. I'm using Glassfish Server and MySql. No frameworks. Using Servlet, JSP and EJB.

Now I'm  querying database through JSP page and displaying results. Is this the best way? or Should I use servlet for querying database and displaying results in JSP?

I want to display only part of the resultset object and show the remaining if the user wants to see it. So Could I implement this using jsp alone?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend usind your Servlet to handle the database-connunication only and perhaps some logging on the usage of the Connection. The logic would best be implemented in JSP alone since you can better maintenance it.

Answer (score 0):

Querying database through JSP page is not the best way. And because you are not using any framework is definitely not the best way to learn. While learning you need to try as much frameworks as possible to find out which one you can use or not to use. You are also need to learn patterns for building Java EE applications.

> Should I use servlet for querying database and displaying results in jsp?

This approach is much better, but is not enough because of coupling database code with servlet code.

> I want to display only part of the resultset object and show the remaining if the user wants to see it. So Could I implement this using jsp alone?

What do you want to display should be coded in the servlet.

Comment: "but is not enough because of coupling database code with servlet code." Then How should I do?

Comment: *How should I do?* I don't know what are you doing? Start doing something, then if you have a concrete question comeback and post a question. If you luck then somebody post the answer.

Comment: No, I'm asking is there any other method of querying database and displaying it. Other than doing it in servlet and jsp?

Comment: First time you asked for querying database using servlet, because you were doing it in JSP. I don't know what you ask, may be JPA?

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid coding your business logic codes in your JSPs. Segrate your application into multiple layers, take a look at [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

- **Model**: These are plain POJO classes where your DB transaction and business logic happens.
- **Controller**: This is where your servlets goes. These classes accept user request, call  appropriate Model classes and send response to view.
- **View**: This is you JSPs, displays data to users. Avoid using Scriptlets in your Jsps. Use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) and [EL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html).

Take a quick look at [this](http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/08/11/mvc-architecture-with-servlets-and-jsp/) example MVC application, and do your own searching on MVC. Hope it helps you to get started.